Show app tray on all display monitors in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 with Dash to Panel extension and 3 monitors. The issue I'm having is that the App tray icons are only being placed in the center monitor. I need it to be placed on all monitors but I couldn't find it anywhere. I don't even know if this is a OS feature or if it's a Dash to panel feature.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?
